# Sitecore Template Source Query issue

Tags: sitecore-query

So I have a multilist with search field that I ONLY want to add the items under my home folder per region. So I want my us site settings file to only pull in the US home items and then the CA Site settings to bring in CA only home items.

[image]

Currently my query is returning all of the items under CA, UK and US. Here is my query figure its something small but cant track it down.

```
query:../home//*[@@templatename='ContentPage_LeftNav' or @@templatename='ContentPage']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using a `Multilist with Search` field, but supplying it with the source query used for a standard `Multilist` field.

On the `Multilist with Search` field, you are writing a query against the index vs using Sitecore Query.

Start with `StartSearchLocation`, in your case you would want something like `StartSearchLocation=/sitecore/content/US/home`, then you can add in a template filter, using the Guids of the templates vs the template names. So the source field would look something like:

```
StartSearchLocation=/sitecore/content/US/home&TemplateFilter={GUID}|{GUID2}
```

If you wanted to have your `StartSearchLocation` relative to the current item you are on, then you can use a query there too like this:

```
StartSearchLocation=query:./../home&TemplateFilter={GUID}|{GUID2}
```

References: https://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/2017/01/17/multilist-with-search-secret-sauce/